# RegExp in VBA: remove excess numbers if there is a text/special character that appears after a certain length of numbers

Tags: regex, vba, excel

Currently my code removes all the text and special characters within the cell value and leaves only the numbers.

the only thing left to do is to remove the numbers after a text/special character appears after a certain length

Example.

412074442 (y) 2367

My code only outputs this as 0412 074 4422367 but it should be 0412 074 442
removing the excess numbers after the "(y)"

```
Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "^4(\d\d)(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d)"
Dim strReplace As String: strReplace = "04$1 $2 $3"
Dim strPattern2 As String: strPattern2 = "[^0-9]"
Dim strReplace2 As String: strReplace2 = ""

Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A8") '***change range to determined text

    For Each cell In Myrange
        If strPattern2 <> "" Then
            strInput = cell.Value

            With regEx
                .Global = True
                .MultiLine = True
                .IgnoreCase = False
                .Pattern = strPattern2
            End With

            If regEx.test(strInput) Then
            'MsgBox (regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace))
                cell.Value = regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace2)

            Else
            'MsgBox ("Not matched")
            End If
        End If
    Next

        For Each cell In Myrange
            If strPattern <> "" Then
                strInput = cell.Value

                With regEx
                .Global = True
                .MultiLine = True
                .IgnoreCase = False
                .Pattern = strPattern
                End With

            If regEx.test(strInput) Then
            'MsgBox (regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace))
                cell.Value = regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace)

            Else
            'MsgBox ("Not matched")
            End If
            End If
        Next

    For Each cell In Myrange
                strInput = cell.Value

        If Len([strInput]) <> 12 Then
        'MsgBox "Error"
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        Else
        End If

        If Len([strInput]) = 0 Then
        'MsgBox "Error"
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        Else

        End If
    Next
End With
```

Need help, Thanks.

Comment: What is your regex pattern?

Comment: So it should be inserting zeroes as well? And how is it preserving the leading? Is this text?

Comment: What is the value of `strPattern ` and `strPattern2`? Don't you think that's relevant?

Comment: Sorry forgot to include:

Answer (score 0):

You may change a bit the architecture of the solution. Thus, the following:

- First look for the `(y)` and cut anything to the right of it.
- Then use the RegEx to remove the non-numeric characters.

This is the code for the removal of the parts right from (y):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim location As Long
    location = InStr(1, Range("A1"), "(y") - 1

    If location > 0 Then
        Range("a1") = Left(Range("a1"), location)
    End If

End Sub
```

[Left Function MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/left-function)

Comment: thanks for this @Vityata, but could it be possible to capture any other text or number or special character? there are cases where there are different Alphanumeric characters after the first 10 numbers.